# Change data for array of objects

Tags: javascript, chess

I'm trying to create a chess game by javaScript.
my problem is when I make the chess move, I change the value position of my chess object. The chess can move to the new position but after rendering the chessboard, the previous chess piece is not deleted.
Here is my code:

```
    const switchCurrentSquare = (selector, curr) => {
      let position = chess.forEach(item => {
        if(JSON.stringify(item.currentSquare) == JSON.stringify(selector)){
            item.currentSquare = curr
            renderChessItems(chess)
        }
    })
}
```

I check for each item in my array of objects, if it has the same position value (current square), it will change to the new position. Here is the code I get the position by click function:

```
    const allClass = document.querySelectorAll('div:not(.board)')
let chessSelector

allClass.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("click", function () {

        const currentSquare = JSON.parse(this.getAttribute("id"))
        changeColorForSelectPiece(currentSquare)
        const pieceType = this.classList[2]
        const player = this.classList[3]
        
        if(chessSelector){
            switchCurrentSquare(chessSelector, currentSquare)
            removeClass()
            chessSelector = null
        }else{
            getNextStep(pieceType, currentSquare, player)
            if(player){
                chessSelector = currentSquare
            }
            else chessSelector = null
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: I try to remove class and attribute style for the old piece and it works, but I thought that if the object change and re-render the IU the old one should be removed?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest an OOP approach, because this could become really complicated down the road.

With OOP this would be easy as well:

```
export class ChessBoard {
  private __state: string[][];

  constructor() {
    this.__state = new Array(8);

    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      this.__state[i] = new Array(8);
    }
  }

  public render(): void {
    // Render the chessboard
  }
}
```

I wrote this in TypeScript, which I highly recommend too for a project like this.

You could just update your current state and re-render your chessboard, then display that on the web.

The state would look like something like this:

```
[
  [BlackRook], [BlackKnight], [BlackBishop], [BlackKing], [BlackQueen], [BlackKnight], [BlackBishop], [BlackRook],
  [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn],
  [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
  [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
  [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
  [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
  [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn],
  [WhiteRook], [WhiteKnight], [WhiteBishop], [WhiteKing], [WhiteQueen], [WhiteBishop], [WhiteKnight], [WhiteRook],
]
```

And after each move, update the state and re-render the ui:

```
[
  [BlackRook], [BlackKnight], [BlackBishop], [BlackKing], [BlackQueen], [BlackKnight], [BlackBishop], [BlackRook],
  [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn], [BlackPawn],
  [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
  [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
  [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
  [], [], [WhiteKnight], [], [], [], [], [],
  [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn], [WhitePawn],
  [WhiteRook], [], [WhiteBishop], [WhiteKing], [WhiteQueen], [WhiteBishop], [WhiteKnight], [WhiteRook],
]
```

**EDIT**

This is how I would iterate through the state:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.__state.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < this.__state[i].length; j++) {
    if (this.__state[i][j] instanceof EmptyField) {
      // move
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Created a git repo for this: https://github.com/kmpizmad/js-chess

You can run it with `node ./build/index.js` and you'll see the initial state.
Do whatever you want with it. :D feel free to rebuild the structure if it doesn't work for you.

***Hierarchy:***

`Game`: this controls the whole program

`Chessboard`: this controls the squares

`Graveyard`: similar to `Chessboard` but it controls the fallen pieces instead

`Piece`: abstract class, contains each prop that every piece has.

Everything else is a child of `Piece`

Comment: I check my array of objects after render, it changes to the new one, it shows me 32 pieces with the new state, but the old one didn't change :(((, thank you for your explanation, but do you have any recommendations for my issue. I try to remove the class, attribute style of the old one but I thought that if I changed the object and re-render it the old one should be removed.

Comment: It would be hard to explain my approach since OOP requires kind of a core structure, otherwise it will simply fall apart 100%. Uhm.. I'll update my answer with my structure, but until then, please post your code cuz I'm having a hard time imagining this

Comment: Here is my code https://github.com/Portgasdax99/training-chess